# Match string on new lines?

Tags: .net, string

So I've been looking over the `File.ReadAllText` function within .NET and I've worked out how to search a text file to match a string, however...

How can I search on a **per line bases**? For example let's say I have a text file as below

```
Names

HarryS1
HarryS2
HarryS3
```

Of course I can use something like:

```
Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("names.txt")
        Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf(HarryS)

        If index >= 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Name Found")

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Name not found")
        End If
```

However, it will always say it's found because HarryS exists more than once within the text file. - Do I need to use a regex to search for a string? Or can I get it to check on a per line bases?

Answer (score 0):

It says text.IndexOf(HarryS). Shouldn't it say text.IndexOf("HarryS")? Anyway, there are many approaches to what you want to do, depending on what are your performance and flexibility requirements. In your case, the simplest check is:

```
Try
    Dim text As String = vbCrLf & System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\names.txt") & vbCrLf
    Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf(vbCrLf & "HarryS2" & vbCrLf)
    If index >= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Name Found")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Name not found")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Exception found!" & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
End Try
```

If you need further flexibility, the most powerful way I can think of to achieve this sort of thing is through LINQ and a RegEx expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
     Try
        FileOpen(1, "FilePath", OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.LockWrite)
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        While (EOF(1) = 0)
            Dim readData As String = LineInput(1)
            If readData = "HarryS" Then
                found = True
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
        If found = True Then
            MsgBox("Found")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not found")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Finally
        FileClose(1)
    End Try
```

### Synopses

Here the `FileOpen` function opens the file path with the parameters and with a key reference of number `1`. This is the key for referring the file data or any other transaction with the file. Then the variable `found` is used for confirming the finding inside the file. Next we use a While Loop for fetching data from the file. There the function `LineInput(1)` is your answer, fetch data form file line by line as String data type. Then we can compare the data just like a string comparison and search the entire file for the match. As we found a match we change the value of the variable `found = True`. Then after the loop we creates another comparison to ensure the finding and throw the response with message box. Finally the `FileClose` function close the file.

Answer (score -2):

Source: [StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Test

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt" 

        Try 
            If File.Exists(path) Then
                File.Delete(path)
            End If 

            Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path)
            sw.WriteLine("This")
            sw.WriteLine("is some text")
            sw.WriteLine("to test")
            sw.WriteLine("Reading")
            sw.Close()

            Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)

            Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
                Dim text As String = sr.ReadLine()
                Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf(HarryS)

                If index >= 0 Then
                   MessageBox.Show("Name Found")

                Else
                   MessageBox.Show("Name not found")
                End If
            Loop
            sr.Close()
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString())
        End Try 
    End Sub 
End Class
```